# Sequential Insertion without Colliding Numbers from Multiple Users and IP Addresses

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question about sequential insertion of data without conflicting numbers when multiple users/ip addresses simultaneously submit entries. I have 2 columns in my database table : "ID" and "NO". The "ID" serves as unique identifier, while "NO" represents the order number which sequencing the number that user insert.

For Example, If User A and User B submit at the same time, there's possibility that the "NO" data is duplicate because it is hit at the same time.

I create a function that will generate the "NO" format but there is still duplication in "NO".

Here's my function :

```
FUNCTION get_next_no
(
 P_TYPE        IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;

v_last_sequence     INT;
v_no                VARCHAR2(24 Byte);

BEGIN        
    SELECT  MAX(SUBSTR(no,17,8))
    INTO    v_last_sequence
    FROM    P_MAIN
    WHERE   TO_CHAR(p_date, 'YYYYMM')  = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMM')
    AND     TYPE = P_TYPE
    ;

    IF v_last_sequence IS NULL THEN
        v_last_sequence := 0;
    END IF;
    
    IF P_TYPE = 'CONV' THEN
        v_no := 'CERC-00-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') || '-' || LPAD(v_last_sequence + 1, 8, '0');
    ELSE 
        v_no := 'CERS-00-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') || '-' || LPAD(v_last_sequence + 1, 8, '0');
    END IF;
    

    RETURN v_no;
END get_next_no;
```

Any guidance or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank You!

I am seeking a solution or approach to handle this scenario effectively, guaranteeing that the "NO" values assigned are sequential and unique, even when multiple users or IP addresses submit concurrently.

Comment: I suggest not trying to reinvent sequences... use a real Oracle sequence and it will handle the concurrency issue for you. It won't recycle to 0 for every distinct value of some column, but you don't really want that anyway, it's a violation of normalization rules because it tries to tell you something about the row's order within a set of rows, and that can become inconsistent, creating multiple versions of truth. That's something you want to avoid. If you need a sub-sequence within each distinct value, compute that at query time, don't store it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Paul. Are you suggesting that I use the Oracle sequence for the ID column or can it be used for my "v_no" variable? because the "last_sequence" will be reset to 0 when the month changes. And what do you mean by sub-sequence? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm referring to `v_no`. If you already have a primary key (`ID` maybe?) then you don't need any further sequencing. I'm saying that what you're trying to do with `v_no` is a design no-no.  You don't want multiple pieces of information in the same column, dates expressed as strings, and a second sequencing variable all compacted into one long string, especially when you are having to use a substring to get the starting value as a result. Use separate columns for every piece of information. Store dates as dates, not as strings. And compute intra-group order at query time, not in a data column.

Comment: At query time: `select x.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(p_date,'MM'),type ORDER BY created_date,id) intra_month_sequence FROM p_main x`

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way would be just to use a standard sequence object and stop worrying about gaps in the "NO".  That way, no duplicates, no locking, no worries.

If you really wanted to go down the path of no gaps, you'll need a separate table plus some locking logic to serialise the access. For a reasonably scalable solution to this, there's some code below, and I walk through it here

https://youtu.be/B5JltFoe5Ho

```
create table seqs
  ( name   varchar2(100),
    constraint seqs_pk primary key ( name )
  )
organization index ;

insert into seqs
select 'SEQ'||rownum
from dual
connect by level <= 5;

select * from seqs;

create table seqs_numbers
  ( name   varchar2(100),
    num    number(10),
    state  varchar2(10),
    constraint seqs_numbers_pk primary key ( name,num ),
    constraint seqs_numbers_fk foreign key ( name) references seqs ( name ) on delete cascade,
    constraint seqs_numbers_ck check ( state in ('free','used'))
  )
organization index ;

insert into seqs_numbers
select s.name, num, 'free'
from   seqs s,
       ( select level num from dual 
         connect by level <= 1000 );
commit;

select * from seqs_numbers
where  name = 'SEQ1'
and    rownum <= 12;


create or replace
function get_seq(p_name varchar2) return number is
  l_seq number;
  cursor next_seq is
    select num
    from   seqs_numbers
    where  name = p_name
    and    state='free'
    order by num
    for update skip locked;
begin
  open next_seq;
  fetch next_seq into l_seq;
  close next_seq;
  update seqs_numbers
  set    state = 'used'
  where  name = p_name
  and    num = l_seq;
  
  return l_seq;
end;
/
```

But seriously... go with a sequence

Comment: Hi Connor, Thankyou for your suggestion. But the "NO" format needs to reset every month. I have edited and added the function code above. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: No real drama there. You would lock the table at the start of the month, and re-insert the values from 1 onwards up to the expected limit.